# Mostrar datos de arrays asociativos en una tabla HTML

Tags: php

Necesito cargar estos datos en una tabla, cuestión que intento mostrar los encabezados, pero en el encabezado de las fechas necesito que este toda esas fechas en una sola columna de la tabla y no me sale..
¿me podrían ayudar?

```
    <?php 


    echo "<p> <h2> Punto 1: de Asistencias de la materia Programación III </h2>   </p>";
    echo "<p> b)_ Tabla en pantalla </p>";


    $alumnos=array( "10"=>"ACOSTA CARLOS ALBERTO",
                    "29"=>"AGUILERA CAPRA JESUS DARIO",
                    "34"=>"AYALA LEANDRO JOSE",
                    "45"=>"BENITEZ DARIO",
                    "52"=>"BRITEZ PABLO FERNANDO",
                    "65"=>"CANESIN LUIS OSCAR",
                    "79"=>"DEGREGORIO NICOLAS EZEQUIEL",
                    "84"=>"FERNANDEZ VICTOR HUGO",
                    "9"=>"BOGADO EZEQUIEL",
                    "103"=>"IZA FEDERICO",
                    "117"=>"GIMENEZ MARIANA ITATI",
                    "124"=>"BRITEZ MENDEL JUNIOR JOEL");


$fechasAsistencias=array("Fechas"=>array("30/09"=>array('-','P','P','P','P','P','P','P','P','P','P','P'),"06/10"=>array('-','P','-','P','P','-','P','-','P','P','-','P'),"07/10"=>array('P','P','P','P','P','P','P','P','P','-','P','P'),"13/10"=>array('P','P','P','-','-','P','P','P','-','P','P','P'),"14/10"=>array('P','-','P','P','-','P','P','-','P','-','P','P'),"20/10"=>array('P','P','-','P','P','-','P','P','-','P','P','-'),"21/10"=>array('P','P','P','P','-','P','P','P','P','-','-','P'),"27/10"=>array('P','P','P','P','P','P','-','P','-','P','-','P')));


    echo "<table border=5 >";

    echo "<thead>";

        echo "<tr>";

            echo "<td> <th> Nro.  </th> </td>";

            echo "<td><th> Apellido y Nombre </th></td>";

//Aqui esta mi problema necesito este encabezado fecha, y las fechas como sub encabezados en la misma columna. el problema es que me muestra uno a lado del otro.. y nose como de otra forma probarle..

        echo "<td><th> Fechas </th> <td>30/09</td><td>06/10</td><td>07/10</td><td>13/10</td><td>14/10</td><td>20/10</td><td>21/10</td><td>27/10</td></td>" ;




        echo "</tr>";



    echo "</thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";

    echo "</tbody>";

echo "</table>";

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php


$alumnos=array( "10"=>"ACOSTA CARLOS ALBERTO",
                "29"=>"AGUILERA CAPRA JESUS DARIO",
                "34"=>"AYALA LEANDRO JOSE",
                "45"=>"BENITEZ DARIO",
                "52"=>"BRITEZ PABLO FERNANDO",
                "65"=>"CANESIN LUIS OSCAR",
                "79"=>"DEGREGORIO NICOLAS EZEQUIEL",
                "84"=>"FERNANDEZ VICTOR HUGO",
                "9"=>"BOGADO EZEQUIEL",
                "103"=>"IZA FEDERICO",
                "117"=>"GIMENEZ MARIANA ITATI",
                "124"=>"BRITEZ MENDEL JUNIOR JOEL");

?>
```

asi quieres la tabla?

```
<table width="100%" border="1">



 <?php

   foreach($alumnos as $key => $value)
      {


 ?>
    <tr> 
           <td>
               <?php echo $key; ?>
         </td>
                 <?php foreach($value as $key=>$value)
                   {
                 ?>
          <td>
                <?php echo $value;?>
         </td>
                <?php
                 }
                ?>
    </tr>




<?php
    }
   ?>

</table>
```

Comment: Deberias explicar los cambios que hiciste.

Answer (score 0):

Para la parte de las fechas, puedes recorrer el array que tienes definido $fechasAsistencias['fechas'] indicando la clave y el valor:

```
foreach ($fechasAsistencias['fechas'] as $fecha => $lista) {
   // en $fecha tienes 30/09, 07/10 ...
}
```